# How to compare a picture sent by a bot with a picture from my file

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telebot

Please tell me if there are analogs of the operation:

```
if(message.text == "text"):
```

for pictures. I want a certain image to be executed for a certain image.

I tried like this:

```
if(message.photo == "img/1(1).jpg"):
```

```
p = open('img/1 (1).jpg', 'rb')
if(p == "img/1 (1).jpg"):
```

but the result is the same, nothing works

*in general, I need to compare the picture sent by the bot with the picture from my file*

Comment: How would Telebot know whether two images are equal?

Comment: idk, i try like this
```p = open('img/1 (1).jpg', 'rb')
        print(p)
        if(message.p == "img/1 (1).jpg"):
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("smth", url='https://google.com')
            markup.add(button1)
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, p, reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: I decided to try the poke method from ignorance, do not pay attention to the condition